# Does SSIS `Buffer memory` include `Flat buffer memory` and `Private buffer memory`?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, perfmon

I am looking at ssis perf mon counters to check for memory pressure from running ssis packages.

Does SSIS `Buffer memory` include `Flat buffer memory` and `Private buffer memory`?